# Row wise similar data compression Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, etl, data-science

Suppose I have a Dataset

```
A B 
1 k 
1 g 
1 e 
2 g 
2 e 
3 d
```

After applying one hot encoding with pandas i get:

```
A B_k B_g B_e . . . . 
1 1    0   0    
1 0    1   0    
1 0    0   1    
2 .
2 .
3 .
```

I want the output to be

```
A B_k B_g B_e 
1  1   1   1
2  0   1   0
```

And so on.
I would like to get similar row values EG:1 together in column [A] as one row and OHE column [B]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `crosstab` ?

```
pd.crosstab(df.A,df.B)
B  d  e  g  k
A            
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  1  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Not sure if that would work in my case. I want get similar raw's together in column [A] and one hot encode column [B]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` after the one hot encoding:

```
df.groupby(['A']).sum()
>>> 
    B_d  B_e  B_g  B_k
A                    
1    0    1    1    1
2    0    1    1    0
3    1    0    0    0
```